# Daterangepicker not working in ASP.NET when add runat="server"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I using jquery daterangepicker control in asp.net but it not working

```js
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(function () {                                                  
                                            
        $("#<%=single_cal1.ClientID%>").daterangepicker();
     });
                                        
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
                                      
<input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal1" placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">                                        
                                    
                                        
 <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
 </div>

function daterangepicker Bootstrap:
<pre lang="c#">
      $('#single_cal1').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    singleClasses: "picker_1",
    locale: {
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    }
 
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
  });
```

Help me !

Comment: Your code looks fine. Any errors in the console? Have you included all required libraries?

Comment: it may be because you are using ID selector on server control which changes after rendering. you can try like this `$("#<%=single_cal1.ClientID%>")`

Comment: If I remove runat="server" it is working good, I think I add full libraries.